# Core Data & Generating Model Entities

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Standard newbie question. I've created a data model for an iOS application. I am able to create, update and delete entities within the model from various views by using the NSEntityDescription object.

Say if I had a mutable array of objects returned from a fetch request. How can I loop through each one when I do not have a generated object definition from the entity model? By generated object definition I mean, a header and body class definition of the entity described in the data model package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All CoreData entities derive from NSManagedObject and all the database data from those can be accessed via key value encoding. The minimum you need to know can be gained from the Model. You don't necessarily require the headers.

For example an entity **PersonEntity** which has a relationship to **NameEntity** with attribute **firstname**

```
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext queryEntityForName:@"PersonEntity" predicateFormat:nil argumentArray:nil];

for(NSManagedObject *object in results)
{
NSString *name = [object valueForKeyPath:@"nameobject.firstname";
[self doSomething:name];
}
```

queryEntityForName is my own category. You might find it useful.

```
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext(VMQueryAdditions)

-(NSArray *)queryEntityForName:(NSString *)name predicateFormat:(NSString *)pstring argumentArray:(NSArray *)arr
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:self];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *pred;

    if(pstring)
    {
        if(arr) pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:pstring argumentArray:arr];
        else    pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:pstring];
        [fetch setPredicate:pred];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *results = [self executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"MOC Fetch - Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    return results;

}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Warren. Thank you for your answer. NSManagedObject was indeed the class I needed for the 'for' loop.

Comment: Is there an easy way to parse managed objects? For example, having a class to represent an instance of a managed object and all it's properties and relationships to other objects?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want here. An NSManagedObject instance is a representation of a database table entry. You can get all attribute and relationship info for an entity from NSEntityDescription.

Comment: Hi Warren. I wanted to generate classes so I can cast an NSManagedObject to a more descriptive class. One which exposes its properties rather than accessing the key/value pair collection. I did this via the 'File > New > Cocoa Class > Managed Object Class' method which analysed my data model.